# Nested Collections not updating the UI when properties change

Tags: wpf, binding, nested

I had a listbox of user controls and each usercontrol displays properties of the bounded data and bind a collection to custom control when the custom control changes the data the UI not updated my code is as follows :

```
ObservableCollection<Subscription> subscriptions = new ObservableCollection<Subscription> SubscriptionRepository.GetSubscriptions());
            SubListBox.ItemsSource = subscriptions;
```

xaml :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
            <UserControls:SubscriptionUC />
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox x:Name="SubListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}">
</ListBox>
```

user control :

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DaysAttended}" />
<cc:CustomControl SubscriptionSource="{Binding Path=SubscriptionDays,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Subscription class :

```
public class Subscription : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int SubscriptionTypeId { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<SubscriptionDay> SubscriptionDays { get; set; }

        public int DaysAttended { get { return SubscriptionDays.Count(d => d.Attended == true); } }
public void DayChanged()
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("SubscriptionDays");
            RaisePropertyChanged("DaysAttended");
        }
 }
```

DayChanged() is called from SubscriptionDay class when SubscriptionDay property changed and it is called but DaysAttended not updated.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have **setter** for **DaysAttended** property,For Two Way binding it is must that your property should have getter and setter .I hope this will help.

Comment: I am sorry but it did not work. I tried to make the same idea in a test project and it is working I do not know what is the problem in my project!